# PHP try-catch block inside loop

Tags: php, performance, try-catch

Is it less efficient to put a try-catch block inside of a loop as opposed to wrapping the loop with a try-catch in php if it is intended that the loop will end if an exception occurs? Or is there essentially no difference?

EDIT:

i.e.,

```
foreach (/*...*/) {
    //...
    try {
        //...
    } catch (/*...*/) {
        break;
    }
    //...
}
```

versus:

```
try {
    foreach (/*...*/) {
        //...
    }
}
```

Comment: it may be surprised you, but sometimes code being written to be sensible, not to be "more efficient" nonsense. Just sensible. To make a  task it's designated for.

Comment: Could the performance penalty of having a try-catch block inside a loop as opposed to being outside be approximately the same as the penalty for `for ($i = 0; $i < count($array); $i++) {...}` as opposed to `for ($i = 0; $i < $arrayCount; $i++) {...}`

Answer (score 65):

That entirely depends on the nature of the failure, and what you intend to do in the `catch`.

But I'd generalize it like so

- If you want the loop to exit on Exception, wrap the whole loop
- If you want the loop to continue, don't

### EDIT

Exceptions caught *inside* a loop don't implicitly break the loop

```
for ($i = 1; $i < 10; $i++) {
    try {
        if ($i % 3 == 0) {
            throw new Exception('BOOM');
        }
        echo $i;
    } catch (Exception $e) {
        echo "Exception at $i";
    }
    echo PHP_EOL;
}
```

output:

```
1
2
Exception at 3
4
5
Exception at 6
7
8
Exception at 9
```

Whereas those caught *outside* the loop do

```
try {
    for ($i = 1; $i < 10; $i++) {
        if ($i % 3 == 0) {
            throw new Exception('BOOM');
        }
        echo $i, PHP_EOL;
    }
} catch ( Exception $e ) {
    echo "Exception at $i";
}
```

output:

```
1
2
Exception at 3
```

Comment: The loop will break if an exception occurs.

Comment: Not if the exception is caught.  I'll add an example

Comment: I mean the loop is intended to break if an exception is caught: `foreach (...) { try {...} catch(...) { break; } }`

Comment: if you want to break loop on exception , put `try .. catch` outside of the loop.

Comment: good example, thanks!

Comment: If the exception is caught and not thrown again they yes, it will depend on how much the try/catch covers and if it is outside it will break the whole loop, but if u throw it again it will stop the loop also if it is inside, there could be many reasons u would still want to do that like being sure nothing is processed further than this line, but u are only concerned about that line.

Answer (score 2):

That depends entirely on how you are using the try-catch? Is it safe to continue looping through your subject if an exception was thrown?

Answer (score 1):

There is most likely no difference. Optimization on this level does usually not make any sense in an interpreted language like PHP.

In most cases,  your logic will *require* you to put the block inside the loop anyway. Otherwise, the loop will continue even if an error has occurred.

Answer (score 0):

Of course, there's a difference, in the most obvious way int the first case you will only check for errors before entering the loop, if the loop doesn't have exception throwers, leave it that way. In the other hand you will be checking it in each iteration, wich you'll need if you have sentences or methods ... wich can have exceptions.

I'dont know if i explain myself well, let me know if you understand