# How to remove message from imap if loop break

Tags: php, exchange-server, imap

I am using php to read messages from exchange mailbox. The below is just a simple script not a real example.

At some point the 'for' loop sometimes break and I am in process of fixing these issues.

If there are 10 messages and the loop break on the last one the other 9 messages  which supposed to be removed will not be removed because the code break to the expunge is not reach.

Is there a work around so even if the code breaks i could still remove the correct emails which have already been processed for deletion.

```
    //checking how many messages are in the mailbox
    $total = imap_num_msg($inbox);
    //if there are any messages then process them
    if ( $total > 0){
    echo "\nAnalysing Mailbox\n";

    for ($x=$total; $x>0; $x--){
    //doing some work here 

    delete_processed_message($x);
    }

    echo "Please wait, expunging old messages\n";
    imap_expunge($inbox);
    echo "Please wait, disconnecting from mail box\n";
    imap_close($inbox);
```

Many Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

One alternative would be to wrap you `delete_processed_message($x)` in a [try-catch block](http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_exception.asp) (official documentation can be found [here](http://php.net/manual/en/language.exceptions.php)). That way, even if it throws an exception (which is probably the reason it's breaking), it'll continue with the rest of the messages.

The code should look like this

```
...
for ($x=$total; $x>0; $x--){
    //doing some work here 
   try {
        delete_processed_message($x);
   } 
   catch (Exception $e) {
        //Here you can log it to a file, or simply echo it 
       echo 'Caught exception: ',  $e->getMessage(), "\n";
   }

}
...
```

And like it was explained in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4673483/php-try-catch-block-inside-loop), using the try-catch inside the for loop makes sure the for finishes.